# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 34

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

**EDIT**:

Since the data is now showing if I do `hot reload` after the error. I am assuming that my other `Future`that isn't included in my `FutureBuilder` triggers that error.

**HERE ARE THE ACTUAL FUNCTIONS:**

```
     List<Feed> feedList = [];
      List<User> userList = [];

     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        getFeed = getFeedAll();
        this.getUsers();
      }

 Future<List<Feed>> getFeedAll() async {
    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(APIServices.httpDomain + APIServices.postGetAll),
        headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + Constants.token});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);
      this.getUsers();
      feedList = data.map<Feed>((json) => Feed.fromJson(json)).toList();
    }

    return feedList;
  }

  Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(APIServices.httpDomain + APIServices.usersAll),
        headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + Constants.token});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);

      userList = data.map<User>((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
    }

    return userList;
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getFeed,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: feedListWidget(snapshot.data));
        } else {
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Now, I am using `userList` inside my `feedListWidget` widget.

I am pretty sure that `getUsers()` triggers that error.

How can I include `getUsers()` inside my `FutureBuilder`?

Because that's what I think will solve my problem.

Comment: Could you please share feedListWidget()'s code?

Comment: Provide the Feed class would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the hint guys. I've edited my question. That narrows my problem.

Comment: feedListWidget just receives userList? So what is feedList for?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not waiting for the data here:

```
getFeed = getFeedAll();
this.getUsers();
```

Use `await` to perform that

```
getFeed = await getFeedAll();
await this.getUsers();
```